# jcabi @RetryOnFailure cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, annotations, jcabi

jcabi `@RetryOnFailure` cannot be resolved to a type.

I have added both 'weaving' and jcabi dependency in my pom.xml

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>ajc</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

....

   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcabi-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>0.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.12</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But `@RetryOnFailure` is not recognized. Am I missing something here?

Comment: did you get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following dependency in pom.xml and it is working for me. Update the version for both.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcabi-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>0.22</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```